# Django-Dashing Custom Widget HTML Location

Tags: javascript, html, django, dashing, rivets.js

I'm using the Django-Dashing framework (https://github.com/talpor/django-dashing), and I can't figure out where to place my HTML file for the custom widget that I am using.

I have the following code in my `dashboard.html` file, which is being loaded properly.

```
{% extends 'dashing/base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block stylesheets %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '../../static/widgets/timetables/timetables.css' %}">
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '../../../../static/css/analytics/widgets/timetables.css' %}">-->
{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static '../../static/widgets/timetables/timetables.js' %}"></script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static '../../../../static/js/analytics/widgets/timetables.js' %}"></script>-->
{% endblock %}

{% block config_file %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static '../../static/dashing-config.js' %}"></script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static '../../../../static/js/analytics/dashing-config.js' %}"></script>-->
{% endblock %}
```

I also believe I properly defined my `TimetablesWidget` class properly in  `widgets.py`, and its corresponding JavaScript class name `Timetables` properly, as all of the data is being correctly fetched when the widget renders.

I did a `console.log` statement to make sure that the data was being fetched properly, and it indeed is. However, it is not rendering correctly in the `div` on the screen, which makes me think that my `timetables.html` file is not actually being loaded.

Based on where I defined my other paths, could someone let me know where I am supposed to put my HTML file, or perhaps correct me if I am doing something else wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can static file feature of Django

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/